# How to hide standard Report FOLDERS from users

Tags: reporting, reports-folder

Can i hide Standard report folders from users in org. Or can i move them into a custom folder.?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hide them using edit button which is available on hovering on report as shown below.

N.B. Users with Manage Public Reports will still see those folders, but other users will not. There's no way to hide these folders from administrators.

[image]

[image]

Comment: N.B. users with Manage Public Reports will still see those folders, but other users will not. There's no way to hide these folders from administrators.

Comment: I am system admin but not able to see edit option ...after clicking on report folder..   I can see Pin to Top and Share but not Edit

Comment: Never mind......

Comment: @sfdcfox sorry I forgot to mention. thanks for your input.